# How to count a loop using Rspec Capybara & Factory Girl in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, capybara

This question is about a **test** I make to verify that all 50 micropost in the user page are displayed

I have this rspec code:

```
          before(:all) { 50.times {FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, 
                                   user:user, content: "Lorem Ipsum") } }
```

and I want to make each content be more dynamic such as:

```
"Lorem Ispum 0"
"Lorem Ipsum 1"
"Lorem Ipsum 2"
...
```

I tried to write:

```
let(:count_helper) { 0 }
before(:all) { 50.times {FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, 
                                       user:user, 
                                       content: "Lorem Ipsum #{count_helper}") 
                         count_helper += 1} }
```

and it fails here:

```
count_helper += 1
```

How can I write it right?

Comment: What does 'right' mean?  What are you actually trying to achieve

Comment: you already have the 50.. loop, what do you want done with the count_helper variable?  Insert into the db with each row?

Comment: I am trying to create 50 microposts for the user I have created. and I want each micropost to be with a different content. the first post's content will be "Lorem Ipsum 0", the second will be "Lorem ipsum 1" ... the last will be "Lorem Ispum 49"

Comment: Michael, to summarize my question is: if I write in ruby 50.times { puts "this is loop no. #{loop_number}"}. How do I know the number of the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
let(:count_helper) { 0 }
before(:all) { 50.times {FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, 
                                       user:user, 
                                       content: "Lorem Ipsum #{count_helper}");
                                       count_helper += 1 } }
```

Notice the semi-colon at the end of `FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user:user, content: "Lorem Ipsum #{count_helper}")`

Since, you are using single-line block syntax, you should tell Ruby explicitly that the `count_helper += 1` is another statement.

Comment: thanks for the help. the first problem I had was the issue you were describing. the second one (rspec probably doesn't support "+" - I solved it by passing 50.times do |count|.. then I could use the variable "count" to count the contents..

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code should be written:

```
    before(:all) { 50.times do |count|
                     FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user:user, 
                     content: "Lorem Ipsum #{count}") 
                   end }
```

I had 2 mistakes:

1. creating 2 code lines when only one is allowed inside `{}` - I changed it to the `do ... end`
2. I added |count| variable to the loop which helped me count through the loop